# How do I build and compile C++ in VSCode?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I recently installed VSCode to get started on C++. VSCode is installed, and I followed their guide to get started with C++: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc

Now when I go to build their mentioned program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

this is what the terminal shows:

```
> Executing task: clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.out --debug <

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I had installed XCode too as the VSCode website told to download it as a compiler for C++ in macOS.

Comment: ***missing xcrun at*** https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a

Comment: The program is building now, but I'm facing 2 more problems. 1 - There are squiggly line beneath the header files, the error being:  `#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/Users/yuvanseth/Documents/VS/helloworld.cpp).C/C++(1696)`, with the quick fix being to install vcpkg. 2 - The output isn't in the terminal, it's in a separate .out file, which itself is in binary.